# Bash script doesn´t download a FTP file (lftp)

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, ftp, sftp

When I'm trying to download a file from a FTP by the following bash script on a EC2 AWS linux machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The 4 variables below store server and login details
HOST="host"
USER="user"
PASSWORD="pass"
DESTINATION="folder"

lftp $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
login $USER $PASSWORD
cd $DESTINATION
get FuturesMarketData_20220301.csv 
bye
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

and I'm receiving the folowing output:

```
FuturesMarketData_20220301.csv' at 0 (0%) [Receiving data]
```

and never download it...

If I did it manually, all works fine, and i get the file... can anyone help me?

Comment: If you login to the EC2 instance and manually run `lftp` and run those commands, does it work? What is the configuration of the _Outbound_ rules of the Security Group associated with that EC2 instance?

Comment: Hi, @JohnRotenstein , yes it works if I did it manually.. I have all Outbound rules allowed, all trafic from 0.0.0.0...